# How to group/select JSON type column (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I wanna do

```
<MODEL>.select("brief_content").group("brief_content")
```

Here's the table scheme ,

```
                :id => :integer,
           :content => :json,
     :brief_content => :json
```

But I got the errors,

How can I do, Thanks

```
companyAlarmLog Load (0.9ms)  SELECT company_alarm_logs.id, company_alarm_logs.name, company_alarm_logs.utc_time, company_alarm_logs.company_alarm_test_id, company_alarm_logs.brief_content, brief_content FROM "company_alarm_logs" GROUP BY brief_content ORDER BY utc_time
E, [2014-06-24T09:40:39.069988 #954] ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: ...t, brief_content FROM "company_alarm_logs"  GROUP BY brief_cont...
                                                             ^
: SELECT company_alarm_logs.id, company_alarm_logs.name, company_alarm_logs.utc_time, company_alarm_logs.company_alarm_test_id, company_alarm_logs.brief_content, brief_content FROM "company_alarm_logs"  GROUP BY brief_content  ORDER BY utc_time
Hirb Error: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
LINE 1: ...t, brief_content FROM "company_alarm_logs"  GROUP BY brief_cont...
```

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there's no simple way to do direct `json` equality tests in 9.3.

9.3's `json` type has no equality operator, because it accepts json with duplicate keys (as many implementations expect). It isn't clear if `{"a":1, "a":2}` is "equal" to `{"a":1}` or not.

9.4 adds `jsonb` which collapses duplicate keys on a last-key-wins basis, making equality unambiguous.

```
regress=# SELECT '{"a":1, "a":2}'::json = '{"a":1}'::json;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = json
LINE 1: SELECT '{"a":1, "a":2}'::json = '{"a":1}'::json;
                                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

regress=# SELECT '{"a":1, "a":2}'::jsonb = '{"a":1}'::jsonb;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Unfortunately, this means you can't do what you want simply in 9.3.

You could write a custom equality operator for `json` - perhaps just casting both to text and comparing that way, but that'd treat `{"a":1, "b":2}` and `{"b":2, "a":1}` as unequal.

A better option would be to install PL/V8 and use the V8 JavaScript engine's json operations to perform the equality comparison.

Define an equality operator for `json`, then define a simple b-tree opclass using that operator. Both are simple to do at the SQL level - see `CREATE OPERATOR` and `CREATE OPERATOR CLASS`.

Once you've done that you'll be able to `GROUP BY` json values in 9.3.

Or you could just install 9.4 beta1 and use `jsonb`.

Answer (score 1):

`.group('brief_content:text')` should do the trick. Anyway it can be not accurate, when fields have different order in serialized json. In rails this should not be a problem.