# Postgresql: single group by expression doesn't violate GROUP BY rules. Why?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.3 on Ubuntu.

I have a table a bit like this

```
CREATE TABLE obj 
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  pid bigint,
  oobj json,
  ostamp bigint,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_obj_id" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I wanted to do a query joining the `obj` to its children using the parent id (`pid`), and have the child ids aggregated using `array_agg`.  I came up with this

```
select p.*, array_agg(c.id)
from obj p
  inner join obj c on p.id = c.pid
where p.id = 12345
group by 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

Of course I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378258/2036135): "`ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`". But for some reason the following works!

```
select p.*, array_agg(c.id)
from obj p
  inner join obj c on p.id = c.pid
where p.id = 12345
group by 1;  -- HERE IS THE CHANGE: also group by 1, 2, 4 works
```

The question is how?  Why do I not need to reference the other columns the `group by`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer as I was creating this question, but maybe it will help others.

The answer is there's a new `GROUP BY` feature [as of 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html):

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions **or if the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.**

By referring ONLY to the `id` in the `GROUP BY`, you take advantage of that new feature because all the remaining `obj` columns are "functionally dependent" on that `id` primary key.

Somehow, wonderfully that avoids the need for Postgres to do equality checks on the dependent columns (including the `json` column that was causing problems in this case).

Happy days! :)

Comment: You should also note that this behavior is consistent with the ANSI standard.